# Grails Application with JBoss jBPM

Tags: java, grails, jboss, jbpm

I have a application in Grails. now our team has decided to have a work flow system . JBoss  jBPM was the final choice. is it opssible to integrate  jBPM  to grails application?

what are the challenges on integration  jBPM  with Grails?
Is there any other java work Flow engine which is light-weight and easy to integrate with Grails.

we use STS IDE.

Comment: I'm in the same situation. Do you have any experiences to share?

Answer (score 0):

JBoss JBPM is pure java application with hibernate database backend - you can integrate it with grails.

Comment: Yes.  Tomcat has everything necessary for it